# How to cofigure openLDAP with multiple portal instances?

Tags: liferay, openldap

I want to configure openLDAP with mutiple portal instances in liferay. I want to export users into different dn.
for example
for portal instance1, i want to use ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
and for portal instance2,i want to use ou=employee,dc=test,dc=com

Comment: what version of Liferay do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation:

https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/integrating-existing-users-into-liferay

and

https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/ldap

Follow the process for every instance and provide the appropriate filtering.